# prove $\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(n-r)^2\binom{n-1}{n-r}=n(n-1)2^{n-3}$

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

This is problem 2.38 from the book "Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics".

Prove $$\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(n-r)^2\binom{n-1}{n-r}=n(n-1)2^{n-3}$$
I have have been trying different things on and off for two days and still can't derive RHS from LHS.
what I have got so far:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(n-r)^2\cdot\frac{n-1}{n-r}\binom{n-2}{n-r-1}
=(n-1)\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(n-r)\cdot\binom{n-2}{n-r-1}
=\\(n-1)\sum_{r=2}^{n}(n-r)\cdot\binom{n-2}{n-r}
=(n-1)\sum_{r=2}^{n}(n-r)\cdot\binom{n-2}{n-r}
=\\(n-1)\sum_{r=2}^{n}(n-r)\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-r}\binom{n-3}{n-r-1}
=\\(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{r=2}^{n}\cdot\binom{n-3}{n-r-1}
$$
any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that the work you posted has a mistake at the end of the first line, when you change the indices of summation the.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good skill for such problems is knowing how to rewrite expressions in simpler forms. I'd rather write the LHS as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2\binom{n-1}{i}$, letting $i=n-r$. Instead of rewriting this side, I'm going to interpret this combinatorially, meaning I'm going to express it as counting something, and then I'll show that the RHS counts the same thing (hopefully, you've seen such techniques before). We start with a set of $n-1$ elements. The LHS says that we choose $i$ of those elements, where $1\leq i\leq n-1$, and we choose a pair $(a,b)$ of those $i$ elements we picked, where we can have $a=b$. Think of starting with $n-1$ people and forming a committee from some subset of them with a president and treasurer, and the president may also be the treasurer.

Now we need to show that the RHS counts the same thing. Observe that $n(n-1)2^{n-3}=(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-3}+(n-1)2^{n-2}$. Can you see how this also counts the same thing? Hint: consider the case when the president and treasurer are different people, and when they're the same person.

Comment: @Te55eract The most natural way is just to work backwards. I know I want to count committees, and I know the LHS counts by picking the committee, then picking the members, so I ask what if I pick the members first, then the committee. If I do that, I have to consider the two cases I mentioned before, which leads me to those two terms, which I can see are equal to the RHS. It also helps to see that $n$ is unlikely to mean much when I have $n-1$ students, so I try to rewrite the RHS to get rid of the factor of $n$, in which case it's natural to write $n=n-2+2$ and absorb the $2$ into $2^{n-3}$.

Comment: I should note that I've seen this exercise before, and the approach is unintuitive the way the question is written. It would be easier if the RHS in the question were written as $(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-3}+(n-1)2^{n-2}$, making the counting interpretation more obvious, and also making it easy to rewrite as the original RHS. To get the solution here, it's easier just to ignore the RHS, find a second way to count those committees, and show that you get the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,r\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( {n - r} \right)^{\,2} \left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  n - r \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {k^{\,2} \left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {k^{\,2} \left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\left( {k\left( {k - 1} \right) + k} \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {k\left( {k - 1} \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {k\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {k\left( {k - 1} \right){{\left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}}
  + \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {k{{\left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)\sum\limits_{2\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {{{\left( {n - 3} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k - 2\,} } } \over {\left( {k - 2} \right)!}}}
  + \left( {n - 1} \right)\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {{{\left( {n - 2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k - 1\,} } } \over {\left( {k - 1} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)\sum\limits_{2\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  n - 3 \cr 
  k - 2 \cr}  \right)}  + \left( {n - 1} \right)\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  n - 2 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)2^{n - 3}  + \left( {n - 1} \right)2^{n - 2}  =   \cr 
  &  = n\left( {n - 1} \right)2^{n - 3}  \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Rewrite the sum as 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\binom{n-1}{k}.
$$
Note that
$$
\sum_{u=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}x^k=(1+x)^{n-1}-1
$$
and finally note that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\binom{n-1}{k}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[(1+x)^{n-1}-1]\biggr|_{x=1}+\frac{d}{dx}[(1+x)^{n-1}-1]\biggr|_{x=1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 1}^{n - 1}\pars{n - r}^{2}{n - 1 \choose n - r} & =
\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}{n - 1 \choose r}r^{2} =
\left.\partiald{}{x}\pars{x\,\partiald{}{x}}\
\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}{n - 1 \choose r}x^{r}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\partiald{}{x}\pars{x\,\partiald{}{x}}\
\pars{1 + x}^{n - 1}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 1} =
\pars{n - 1}\left.\partiald{}{x}\bracks{x\
\pars{1 + x}^{n - 2}}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{n - 1}\bracks{%
\pars{1 + x}^{n - 2} + \pars{n - 2}x\pars{1 + x}^{n - 3}}_{\ x\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{n - 1}\bracks{2^{n - 2} + \pars{n - 2}2^{n - 3}} = \bbx{n\pars{n - 1}2^{n - 3}}
\end{align}